# How to stream videos through HTML5?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I need to stream videos through HTML5. Is that possible, are there any free sources to try that into my own application?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean just deliver video like Youtube or any other video site, you just use the `<video>` element to deliver it. Its pretty much like displaying an image (JPEG). Its just progressively downloaded to the user's browser. More details about [Video at Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html).

However, if you mean live-stream or streamed to a user such that its not really downloaded, I'm sure there are no way so far to do that without using a solution like a Flash Player client with a streaming server back-end - Flash Media Server, WowzaMedia, Red5, etc, etc.

Comment: What had changed nowadays? Are the tools that help to stream video via HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stream live video through `<video>` tag but it is supported to modern browsers only. so, Have a look at [HTTP Live Streaming checks if browsers/devices support HLS or fallback correctly](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls) to see if live streamming is supported on broswers you are wishing to target

Comment: How can this be live streaming since I can click further in the video and still takes me there?

Comment: @TestTest because HLS-files can be saved for later. It's just a bunch of small video segments and an index-file that is updated live. Apple has a pretty good explanation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html