# Html 5 video streamming issues

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

I setup a server hosting a video as a static file

Then I use html 5 to load and play the video file.

```
 <div id="video wrapper" >
           <video id="video" width="500" height="300" controls> 
                      <source src="/videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
                      Your browser does not support the video type              
            </video>
 </div>
```

According to this discussion, [How to stream videos through HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589322/how-to-stream-videos-through-html5)
ideally the video will be loaded progressively(steamming). But in my case, the video loading seems to block entire page loading and it took several mins before the page finish of page loading and the video starting to play.

the server side has an output like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2013 18:00:23] "GET /videos/test.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 955542769 102.4900
```

I interpret it as:  102 secs to transfer size 9555mb video file "test.mp4".

the test is done with local server(localhost), so I guess it is not network issue. I have no idea how to debug this. Do I need to write a dedicated streaming server instead of hosting a static file?

Any tips for troubleshooting will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a div with an invalid id <div id="video wrapper" > I think you wanted that to be class.

Comment: Also, is the file actually 9.4 GB or is the output in bytes which would make it about 911 MB. Even that is a tall order over the internet you might want to reduce the quality so it's a more manageable size.

Comment: @Charles380 thank you for pointing out my mistakes. Currently, the code and the large file is only used for testing the html5 video tag with my server. I will definitely reduce size of the file later. Any idea for the current problem?

Comment: have you put autoplay on the video tag? otherwise it won't start playing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In mp4,you need to check moov atom.
An atom is a self-contained data unit that contains information about the video file.
just open your mp4 file and check if there is "moov" string in the starting your mp4 file.

For progressive download,the moov atom should be at the beginning of the file.

If the moov atom is at the end of the file,it means progressive download is disabled for the mp4 file.

just run the following linux command.

```
head -c 50 video.mp4
```

output should look like this:

```
ftypisomisomJ??moovlmvhd?%?:?%?:XP?
```